# Serverless Deploy - LogicalResourceId

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless

I have the following serverless.yml file:

https://pastebin.com/9V6AY13e

Whenever I deploy it I get the following error:

```
`Expected params.LogicalResourceId to be a string`
```

Googling this error brings up one or two threads that I don't think are relevant to the reason I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the following lines:

```
deadLetter:
  targetArn:
    GetResourceArn:
      arn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
         - DeadLetterSenderLoader
         - Arn
```

Needed to be:

```
deadLetter:
  targetArn: 'arn:${self:provider.name}:sqs:${self:provider.region}:${self:provider.accountId}:DeadLetterSenderLoader'
```

Answer (score 0):

[AWS::SQS::Queue resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html) has Arn in return values so it can be accessed by [Fn::GetAtt intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html)

The following syntax should work:

```
targetArn:
  Fn::GetAtt: [DeadLetterSenderLoader, Arn]
```

or

```
targetArn:
  Fn::GetAtt:
    - DeadLetterSenderLoader
    - Arn
```